# Wording suggestions for "unhidden", esp given translations

Tags: wording, messages

I am looking for wording suggestions.

There is a panel on my webpage that can be removed by the user.

If a user removes it, a message appears at the top of the screen that says:

- *The "How it Works" panel has been removed. [Undo]*

If the user clicks the "undo" link, the panel re-appears, and a new message appears at the top of the screen:

- *Re-showed the "How it Works" panel.*

I'm trying to think of alternatives for this 2nd message.

What would be best to say here and why?  Please keep in mind that I then need to pass these English versions to translators so that I have the same meaning in multiple different languages.

Maybe:

- Unhid the "How it Works" panel.
- Displayed the "How it Works" panel.
- Showed the "How it Works" panel.
- Re-displayed the "How it Works" panel.
- The "How it Works" panel has been unhidden.
- The "How it Works" panel has been displayed.
- etc?

Comment: Why not just 'added'? Added <-> Removed. Also I suggest posting over at the English stack exchange instead of here.

Comment: Yes, why not: The "How it Works" panel has been added back. So that you also keep a consistent sentence construction with the first message. And the "back" also insists on the fact that the first action is reverted.

Comment: restored seems like a good option

Comment: @ratchetfreak If you provide that as an answer, I'll give you credit for it.  It's what I ended up using.  "Removed" for hiding the panel and "Restored" for the undo (to show it again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Restore** is a good option.

It has the advantage of being familiar with windows.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't having clicked on 'undo' and the visual feedback of the panel re-appearing be enough to help someone realize they are 'unhiding' something? Is a message really necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reporting the activity (was unhidden) report the current status (is visible). Most likely that's also a lot more relevant for the user's context.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't need to include all grammar for notification messages.  You should have them **as short as you can while maintaining clarity**, as they are faster to read, and usually easier to understand.

Then, depending on the exact nature of your application, it may be better to change the first message so that a second one is clearer.  The message combinations I would then suggest are:

- "How it Works" panel **disabled** [undo]
  "How it Works" panel **enabled** [undo]

  These messages don't work well when a panel has settings that you can modify even when it isn't shown.  In that case "disable" is likely to cause confusion.
- "How it Works" panel **hidden** [undo]
  "How it Works" panel **visible** [undo]

  This is clearer when the panel itself is simply not shown, but may still have settings that can be changed while it isn't shown.